# Print / Print preview doesn't working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I clicked print button, the print preview was failed only Google chrome. Other browsers are working fine. I couldn't find out this problem. Why print preview is failed?

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">

function PrintImage() {

    var x = window.open('','_blank','location=0');

    x.document.body.style.margin = '0';

    x.document.body.innerHTML = '';
    x.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    x.document.write("<html style='margin:0px;'><head></head><body onload='printpage()' style='margin:0px;'>");
    x.document.write("<img src='http://10.78.129.248:8080" + $('#imgFront').attr('src') + "' style='margin:0px;border:0px;display:block;height:100%;width:100%;" /* + $('#imgFront').css('height') + "; width:" + $('#imgFront').css('width') + */  + "'/>");
    x.document.write("</body></html>");
    x.document.close();
    x.focus();
    x.print();
    x.close();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="imgFront" src="/badgeimagehandler.jpg" align="middle" border="0" style="width: 80mm; height: 50mm" />

<form>
<input type="submit" name="btnPrint" value="Print" onclick="javascript:PrintImage();" language="javascript" id="btnPrint" /> <!-- -->
</form>

</input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jx7peau4/

Comment: thanks for your help. It is really helpful. but i tried in my local server. Again it is not working. Please could you check in your local server. I am eagerly waiting for your reply..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jx7peau4/1/ You may have to wait until the new image loads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. now print preview is enabled. but image is not there. still it is having some problem. we are trying to solve this issue more than one week. we could not solved it. any other view